# Change to self signed certificate results in communication problem?

Tags: wcf, ssl, certificate

I have a C# client that connects to diffrent services like Elastic Search, IdentityService but also a WCF service. All of them are using a certificate to encrypt communication which have been working great. The problem is that I have to revert to a self-signed certificate and the WCF sevice do not like it at all.

When trying to connect to the service I get “This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case”? I changed the

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

to

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

But that did help. I did get a bit further but not much.

The certificate is generated with this command :

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -sha256 -utf8 -days 365 -nodes -config ./config/tiny_openssl.conf -keyout ./certificates/private.key -out ./certificates/certificate.crt 


# ./config/tiny_openssl.conf    
[CA_default]
copy_extensions = copy

[req]
default_bits = 4096
prompt = no
default_md = sha256
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
x509_extensions = v3_ca

[req_distinguished_name]
C = NO
ST = no
L = no
O = no
OU = myservice
emailAddress = myservice@no.com
CN = myservice Services Titan

[v3_ca]
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alternate_names

[alternate_names]
DNS.1 = 192.168.130.29
DNS.2 = *.192.168.130.29
DNS.3 = app.192.168.130.29
DNS.4 = myservice
DNS.5 = myservice.local
DNS.6 = TITAN.myservice.local
# ...
```

Why do I get these problems? Is there a way to generate a selfsigned certificate that would be granted by WCF just like the "real" one?

Edit : I have added the private key to the selfsigned certificate with openSSL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn’t know which web server you use to host the WCF service and how to bind the particular certificate to a port. But In a Windows OS, I have to add an Https site binding when I use IIS to host the WCF service with transport security.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-configure-an-iis-hosted-wcf-service-with-ssl
In a console application, I usually bind a certificate to the particular port by the below command.

> netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8000
>   certhash=0000000000003ed9cd0c315bbb6dc1c08da5e6
>   appid={00112233-4455-6677-8899-AABBCCDDEEFF}

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-configure-a-port-with-an-ssl-certificate
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/http/add-sslcert
Or the same error will occur when the client-side try to connect the service over HTTPS protocol.

> “This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not
>   configured properly with HTTP.SYS…”

Both `Powershell` and `IIS` have a tool to generate a certificate. It works for me.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/new-selfsignedcertificate?view=win10-ps
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.